# How to leave a field in MongoDB without any changes in an update operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an object to update a document in MongoDB, e.g:

```
let data = {"id": 123, "user": "abc", "is_invalid": "true"}
```

When the field `"is_invalid"` became true for the first time - I'm adding a field of `"invalid_date"`.
If `"is_invalid": "false"` I remove it.
In case that the document has `"is_invalid": "true"`, and `"invalid_date"` already, and I get the object to update again, I don't want the "invalid_date" to change, but stay the same. How can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
let id = data.id;

delete data.id;

let update = {$set: data};

if (user.is_invalid) {
   update.$set.inactivate_time = new Date(Date.now());
} else {
   update.$unset = {
      inactivate_time: 1
   };
}

mongo.collection('users').update(
                {
                    id: id
                },
                update, done);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel  you need to add extra condition in your code, if you already have the access on object. Lets consider a scenario where you will have true and date in the object then you can do following.

```
let data = {"id": 123, "user": "bcd", "is_invalid": "true", "invalid_date":"2021-03-10"}

//you can have a first condition as 

if(data.is_invalid && data.invalid_date){
return; //simply return
}
...
...
//Rest of the code
..
..
```

Comment: I don't really have the object from the document before, and I'd like to prevent one more access to the Mongo.
I get the object data from the user, so I don't want it to hold this date (it can't change)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to do something like this as update query cannot findOne it just updates/overwrites the receving data.

```
const user = await mongo.collection('users').findOne({id: id});
if(!user)
   throw 'No user found'
if(user.is_invalid && !user.invalid_date){
    user.invalid_date = getting.invalid_date;
}
await user.save();
```